# Enable react native android to load downloaded images

Tags: react-native

I have a legacy Android java application into which I am integrating react native. [Per Facebook's instructions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html), I have a generic `Activity` into which I have added the following code:

```
    mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
    mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
            .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();
    mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "HelloWorld", null);
    setContentView(mReactRootView);
```

However, in my case, I have downloaded my react native bundle and placed it in my Android device's cache, so I have amended that example by adding the following call:

`.setJSBundleFile(mReactNativeLocalFile.getAbsolutePath())`

This has enabled me to load my downloaded bundle successfully, however none of the images load. Thus, components that load images like:

`<Image source={require('./img/background.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage} />`

Do not render an actual image.

I have confirmed that all images were successfully extracted and placed in a folder named `assets` adjacent to my bundle. Thus, my folder structure looks like:

```
com.myapp/cache/templates/MyApp/
  index.android.bundle
  assets/
    img/
      background.jpg
```

Thus, can anyone tell me if it is possible for a react native template bundle that has been downloaded locally to the android file system to refer to images that have also been downloaded locally to the android file system?

Answer (score 0):

[Based on this change](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/0fb86c2495157038ded99fc22bfa1e19652989d6), the correct answer is a folder structure on your local disk that looks like this:

```
com.myapp/cache/templates/MyApp/
  index.android.bundle
  drawable-mdpi/
    img_background.jpg
```